# Criar tabela dentro de célula

Tags: javascript, html

Olá. Possuo um script onde preciso adicionar em uma td criada via javascript uma nova tabela. 
Tentei criar diretamente a nova tabela utilizando algo como:

```
var newTable = cell3_prod.createElement("TABLE");
```

Pensei que iria funcionar mas causou erro
Tentei também assim:

```
cell3_prod.appendChild(document.createElement("TABLE"));
var tab_produto = cell3_prod.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
```

Ainda não funcionou.
Isso deveria funcionar ou depende de alguma outra coisa?

Answer (score 1):

Alterei o código para

```
var tab_produto = document.createElement("TABLE");
cell3_prod.appendChild(tab_produto);
```

e funcionou.

Falow!! Valeu!!